# Page Manager URL arguments

Tags: path-aliases, chaos-tool-suite

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't figure out how to get Page Manager and Pathauto to play nice together.

I'm trying to use Page Manager/Panels for a set of pages of a specific node type.  If I use the built-in (System) "node-view" page, the URLs work fine...

`/content/nice-clean-node-title`

But if I try to create my own Pages, I'm forced to use the node id as an argument?

`/content/1`

When you get to the arguments for a URL, there is no option to use node title.

My question is... how do I create variants within Page Manager that deliver node content in different ways based on a (clean) URL...

`/content/some-node-title/overview`

`/content/some-node-title/detail`

`/content/some-node-title/specs`

etc.

Am I missing something?  Or is this really difficult to achieve with Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Node titles are not unique, so they cannot be used directly. You need to create page with nice, machine-readable, numerical ID, and then assign it it's own [URL Alias](http://drupal.org/node/120631). Works similar in Drupal from 5 to 8 as far as I know, menu names might be a bit different, that's all.

Pathauto is nice automation for aliases, but only on nodes. There was already [similar, but not identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706588/drupal-panel-pages-pathauto) with some answers.

Comment: I see, so removing Pathauto from the equation... I would need to create all of the URL aliases manually?

Comment: Either override nodes themselves with panels (linked question, I don't know how but people there says it can be done), create aliases manually, or use pathauto as a code base for writing your pathauto_panels.module and be a hero for many. If there is any other option, well, I hope someone who knows it will add his answer, I would gladly upvote it.